# What can make dns slow in applications, but not in dig/nslookup?

Tags: linux, dns, arch-linux, manjaro

Starting earlier this year, I frequently encounter 10-30 second delays when trying to access new domains, and sometimes for previously visited domains. This happens in multiple programs, including Firefox, Discord's updater, and command line ssh and mosh. For the purpose of testing, I have been using `ssh -vvvv` because it tells me when it starts and finishes the name resolution step. For the purpose of writing this post, I'm accessing the literal domain `asdfasdf.com` which I have not visited previously, but the problem frequently occurs with many different domains and applications.

Opening `http://asdfasdf.com` in Firefox shows a blank tab with a busy animation for 10+ seconds, which I close before it can finish for the sake of further troubleshooting.

`ssh -vvvv asdfasdf.com` reaches `debug3: resolve_host: lookup asdfasdf.com:22` and then pauses for more than 10 seconds. I hit ctrl+c to continue troubleshooting.

`dig asdfasdf.com` produces the appropriate results (a dozen A records) immediately, querying `192.168.1.1` which is my local router and the only nameserver in my `/etc/resolv.conf`

`nslookup asdfasdf.com` produces the appropriate results immediately, but then pauses five seconds and outputs `;; communications error to 192.168.1.1#53: timed out`, pauses, repeats, pauses, repeats, for three total copies of that output, then a final `;; no servers could be reached`

`dig @4.2.2.1 asdfasdf.com` produces the appropriate results (a dozen A records) immediately.

`nslookup asdfasdf.com 4.2.2.1` produces the appropriate results immediately and exits without error

I do `ssh -vvvv asdfasdf.com` again, it reaches `debug3: resolve_host: lookup asdfasdf.com:22` and then pauses for 15 seconds before proceeding to `debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering` and then failing to connect because this arbitrary domain doesn't do ssh of course.

I open the domain in Firefox again, this time the tab is only blank for ~5 seconds then it starts loading the page.

I open the domain in Firefox again, this time it starts loading immediately.

I do `ssh -vvvv asdfasdf.com` again, same 15 second delay.

Changing my `/etc/resolv.conf` nameserver entry to `4.2.2.1` changes the default server for dig and nslookup but doesn't otherwise change any of the results of trying these various steps.

My `/etc/nsswitch.conf` has a line `hosts: mymachines mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] files myhostname dns` which I have tried changing to `hosts: mymachines resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] files myhostname dns` without any obvious effect.

Along the way I tried adding a line to my `/etc/resolv.conf` to stop sending AAAA requests along with every A request. I have lost that line now, but whatever I tried then had no obvious effect.

This problem has persisted across reboots and OS/package updates for months. I haven't found any other suggestions online for what might cause it or how to troubleshoot it.

UPDATE:

`resolvectl status` says `Failed to get global data: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.` because `systemctl status systemd-resolved.service` says the service is disabled and inactive. `systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service` and `systemctl start systemd-resolved.service` get it running.

`resolvectl status` now says the following:

```
Global
          Protocols: +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   resolv.conf mode: foreign
 Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
         DNS Servers 192.168.1.1
Fallback DNS Servers 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 8.8.8.8#dns.google 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google

Link 2 (enp37s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlp38s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
```

`resolvectl query asdfasdf.com` times out after 120 seconds, saying `asdfasdf.com: resolve call failed: Connection timed out`. Just as a control test, `resolvectl query google.com` immediately produces six ip4v and four ipv6 results.

However, having enabled `systemd-resolved.service` seems to have caused Firefox to never start loading pages, so I've stopped and disabled it for further testing.

UPDATE 2:

wireshark tells me that ssh is sending a dns request for an A record and getting a response immediately, then hanging after sending a request for an AAAA record and getting no response.

Further investigation suggests no part of ipv6 is working for me outside my local machine. `ping -6 ::1` works, but `ping -6` to any known outside ipv6 address fails.

I am pursuing disabling ipv6 entirely, or fixing it, and will continue to troubleshoot here and eventually post an Answer once I've found at least one solution.

Comment: does your ISP support IPv6 in a valid and sane way? Yes, you'd be surprised, there are ISP's that either don't support IPv6 at all, or do so in a far from standard/valid/sane way.

Comment: I confess to only reading part of your post, bit it seems to me your local nameserver has multiple resolvers configured and the first one is failing